# C# Set process description on run time or earlier

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I have a WPF Application that starts several "hosted" processes, When i start my WPF Application, It will start the same .exe process couple of times with different arguments in each time.

I want to name each process with a different name (or description) - so I could detect which is which in Task manager (if i want to shutdown one of them).

I understand i cannot set a different process ImageName for each - since they are all the same actual .exe file.

Is there a way I atleast change the process description during run-time, or during its start time (change a ProcessStartInfo parameter or something like that) ..?

Comment: I am just so surprised that nobody advised of tracking the process id... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003975/how-to-get-the-current-processid

Comment: Back then (2013), I wanted unique eady to remember string to each insyance, so I would know each process subject. I did not want to log the id and then compare, the cml argument the guy below proposed is good solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No you can't; the "description" column displays a value that is loaded by Windows when your process starts. It comes from a [version information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) section embedded in the executable file.

What you could do is simply display the "command line" column of task manager.

Comment: Sooooo incredibly sad! :( But a huge thanks for the hint anyway, with the command line column.

Comment: Command line works for me. I can tell my processes apart :).