# Should one call Dispose for Process.GetCurrentProcess()?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

For example, see

[How to get the current ProcessID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003975/getting-the-current-processid-in-net)

No one bothered to call Dispose for an object returned by `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()`. Should it actually be called? Please explain why.

Comment: Simple: If it implements `IDisposable`, call `Dispose`. It may or may not keep a handle to unmanaged memory or some other resource, you just don't know the current implementation, so do it.

Comment: You don't have to call it.  So you got a Yes and a No answer, you still don't know anything.  Don't ask this question.  You can either always dispose, you'll never be wrong.  Or you spend a minute writing a little test app that does it a hundred million times.  Now you know the real answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, and actually it is important too. If you see the actual [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,9270d03e9dfb0fb9), you will see the `Dispose` isn't just inherited from `Component`, it does something too.

It seems to me, looking at that code, that it is most important when `EnableRaisingEvents` is set to `true`, since that involves creating a wait handle. That handle needs to be released in order to prevent memory and handle leaking.

Comment: There is no leak.  A delayed release of a wait handle is pretty innocent, they are the cheapest OS object you could allocate.  Also quite unlikely he subscribed the Exited event for his own process ;)

Comment: @HansPassant: I guess the link was just a sample. When you are doing heavy processing using handles, you might run out of them. And all that even doesn't matter, you should call `Dispose` if the object implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: That's the cargo cult approach.  It doesn't really belong on a site like SO.  But hard to get rid of.

Comment: @HansPassant: Could you translate that to Dutch? ;) Not sure what you mean. In my opinion, if you don't know what it does, it's better to stay on the safe side and call `Dispose`.

Comment: Dat kan.  Een informatief antwoord neemt niet aan dat wat iedereen doet is automaties het korrekte antwoord.  Hebt je het geprobeert?  Makkelijk te doen.

Comment: @HansPassant: lol. English is better. Your Dutch is a little rusty.

Answer (score 5):

That`s a tough call.

You may not have to call `Dispose` for the `Process` instance you got from the `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` in case you did not touch the `Handle` property as well as some other sensitive spots.

Lets have a look at the `Process.Close` method which contains the essence of `Dispose` logic.

```
    public void Close()
    {
        if (this.Associated)
        {
            if (this.haveProcessHandle)
            {
                this.StopWatchingForExit();
                this.m_processHandle.Close();
                this.m_processHandle = null;
                this.haveProcessHandle = false;
            }
            this.haveProcessId = false;
            this.isRemoteMachine = false;
            this.machineName = ".";
            this.raisedOnExited = false;
            this.standardOutput = null;
            this.standardInput = null;
            this.standardError = null;
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

You can see that something real occurs here only if the `Process` instance has a process handle. `Refresh` method has nothing of interest for our topic.

If you look further, you will see that the process handle can be obtained (and thus held) by the `Process` instance when the `Handle` property is accessed. This is **not the only case** though!

```
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            this.EnsureState(Process.State.Associated);
            return this.OpenProcessHandle().DangerousGetHandle();
        }
    }
```

As a generic rule: if it implements `IDisposable` - you ought to call `Dispose`.

In your specific case, if you only touch the current process name or something as innocent, you can omit the `Dispose` call and get away with it.

Here is an example:

```
        Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        var fieldInfo = typeof(Process).GetField("haveProcessHandle", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        var v1 = fieldInfo.GetValue(process);
        //v1 is false. Explicit Dispose is not necessary.

        var processName = process.ProcessName;
        var v2 = fieldInfo.GetValue(process);
        //v2 is false. Explicit Dispose is not necessary.

        var processHandle = process.Handle;
        var v3 = fieldInfo.GetValue(process);
        //v3 is true. Bah. Explicit Dispose IS necessary from now on.
```

I use the reflection for one sole reason: if you monitor the `process` variable via Visual Studio debugger, it is going to walk through the properties and read the dreaded `Handle` property.

`Process` class is a perfect example of a "bad design pattern" as it drastically changes the object state in a get accessor.