# Capturing all windows of an Application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, screenshot, add-in

I am writing an Add in for a Desktop Application. I do not have the access to code the Desktop app but I need to  capture all windows that are related to that from within my Add in. Anything not related to app should not be captured. All windows might not be the new processes. Any idea How can i achieve this?

Comment: The Windows of the Application may be on Different Screens and may have other Apps in Background, but screenshot of only related windows should be captured.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do the following:

1. [Identify the desktop app's process id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003975/how-to-get-the-current-processid) and [any child processed it may have spawned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531828/how-to-enumerate-all-windows-belonging-to-a-particular-process-using-net)
2. Build a list of [all windows that belong to the process id(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531828/how-to-enumerate-all-windows-belonging-to-a-particular-process-using-net) identified previously (try @Konstantin Spirin's proposed solution)
3. Do [a screenshot of each of the windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891345/get-a-screenshot-of-a-specific-application) (try out @Maurice Flanagan's solution)