# How to end the application to copy files from server and open the application again

Tags: vb.net, exe

I have a problem here in my code.I want to delete the existing application exe in my `downloadPath` and copy the new version of the application that is located in `GetFilesFrom`  then open the application again. But after the `proc.Kill()` execute, the next line of code is not continue. Do I have a missing code?

Thank you.

```
    Public CurExeVersion As String = Application.ProductVersion '1.0.1.0 version in my desktop app
    Public version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("\\Bdpc\inhouse apps\Admin Management\Application Files\Admin Management_1_0_0_0\Admin Management.exe")
    Public ServerVersion As String = version.FileVersion '1.0.2.0 version in server
    Dim client As New Net.WebClient
    If CurExeVersion <> ServerVersion Then

        If MessageBox.Show("Update is ready to install", "Do you want to continue?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            Dim processName As String = "Admin Management"
            Dim GetFilesFrom As String = "\\Bdpc\inhouse apps\Admin Management\Application Files\Admin Management_1_0_0_0\Admin Management.exe"
            Dim downloadPath As String = "D:\Admin Management_1_0_0_0\Admin Management.exe"

            If Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).Length > 0 Then
                
                For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)
                    proc.Kill()
                Next

                
                While Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).Length > 0
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
                End While

            End If

            IO.File.Delete(downloadPath)
            IO.File.Copy(GetFilesFrom, downloadPath)
            Process.Start(downloadPath)

        End If
    End If
```

Comment: "not working" is a little bit vague

Comment: I can see a possible problem with the version number comparison: if the one on the server is *older* than the current version, it will replace it. To compare versions, you should use the [Version.CompareTo Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.compareto).

Comment: Could you use a separate updater program? A program killing itself won't be running the next line.

Comment: I just want to replace my exe file in my computer if the version in server is higher. Do I need to use updater?

Comment: @Raffy Yes, you need a separate program to replace the file: you cannot update a program from within itself (unless you want to reboot Windows to do it, which is not very elegant and people will be annoyed at you).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the first process to kill is the one you're running. Maybe change the line:

`proc.Kill()`

to

```
If proc.ID <> Environment.ProcessID Then
    proc.Kill()
End If
```

I haven't tested this code, but it ought to work.

Please reference this, too, where I got the current process: [How to get the current ProcessID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003975/how-to-get-the-current-processid)

Comment: ```Dim currentProcessId As Integer = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id

For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)
    If proc.Id <> currentProcessId Then
       proc.Kill()
    End If
Next```

I added the `currentProcessId` instead of `Environment.ProcessID` I'm having a error if I use that. But nothing happens

Comment: From the link:

"The upcoming .NET 5 introduces Environment.ProcessId which should be preferred over Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id as it avoids allocations and the need to dispose the Process object."